# How can i change the object value in map

Tags: reactjs

```
***//How can I change the select value to true of the checked object?***
```

const App = () => {

```
const data = [{id:1, msg:"t", select:false}, {id:2, msg:"t2, select:false}]

const handleChange = (e) => {
if(checked){
data.select === true
}
}
```

//*``To check the particular object I want to set the value true for that object and rendered the false as an unchecked value*

```
return(
{data.map(d => {
<Checkbox
value={d}
checked={d.select}
onChange-{handleChange}
/>
}
```

)

}

Answer (score 1):

You just have to pass the id to handleChange like this:

```
return(
{data.map(d => {
    <Checkbox
    value={d}
    checked={d.select}
    onChange-{(e)=>handleChange(e,d.id)}
    />
}
```

and change `handleChange` to be something like this

```
const handleChange = (e,id) => {
    const index = data.findIndex(element => element.id === id) // here we get the index of the element 

    if(checked){
        data[index].select = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to say `d.id` in the argument to `handleChange`.

Comment: Yes that's a silly mistake from me i'll change it. Thank you

Comment: data[index].select === true
it is not setting the value to true

Comment: It must be one = sorry that s because i copied from `element.id === id` for some reason xD and of course if you use `useState` upsate the state